# Google play is not showing latest *What's new in this release?*

Tags: google-play

I rolled out my app for 10% users initially(and added some notes under **What's new in this release**), and then rolled out to 100%. Latest version of application is already available to all users but it is showing old text under **What's new in this release?**

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem when I published the latest version of my app  yesterday. The latest version was available in the Play Store soon after publishing but the "What's new in this release" was still showing text from previous version of my app.

To solve this problem, I did this:

1. Go to Release Management -> App releases.
2. Click on Manage Production.
3. Click on the "View all apk details" button (the button with "i" logo) of your latest apk.
4. The apk details window appears. Go to the bottom and enter the desired text in "What's new in this version?"
5. Click "Submit Update".